# DropDownlist VS2012 windowsform

Tags: winforms, visual-studio

I've been trying to create a small program and i need a dropdownlist in it.

On VS2012 i can´t use the form cause the dropdownlist form is System.Web.UI.Webcontrols and i'm creating a Windows Forms Application, so when i add it to the toolbox i get the message that it was added but not enabled.

Is there any other way to create a dropdownlist?

I've been searching but couldn't find any.
If there isn't any other way which template do i have to use to be able to use the controls for the System.Web.UI.Webcontrols? and does it only work for web pages? cause i only want a windows app.

Thanks for the help,
Bruno

Comment: The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) clearly says that `System.Web.UI.WebControls` are only for web apps, as does the name (`System.**Web**.UI.**Web**Controls`). What's wrong with a `ComboBox`?

Comment: Thanks for the help, didn't knew of the combobox control, think it'll work just fine :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.Web.UI.WebControls`, as the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) (and the multiple mentions of **Web** in the name) clearly states, are only for web apps. The equivalent in a `Windows.Forms` application would probably be a [`ComboBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.combobox%28v=VS.80%29.aspx), which is on the `Common Controls` section of the `ToolBox` for a `Windows.Forms` application.

The event you'll most likely want to use is the [`Click`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.control.click.aspx) or [`SelectedIndexChanged` i](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged.aspx)f you're needing to react as soon as something happens. To access the item the user selected, use the [`SelectedIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindex%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (for the numerical position in the list of items) or [`SelectedValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvalue%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (for the content of the item selected). You might also find the [`SelectedItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [`SelectedText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedtext%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) properties of interest.